# Impala -to_timestamp()

Tags: impala, dbeaver, hue, aqua

Impala to_timestamp() returns extra 1 hour

```
SELECT to_timestamp(01051984, ddMMyyyy)
```

returns '1984-05-01 **00**:00:00'.

```
SELECT to_timestamp(01041984, ddMMyyyy)
```

returns '1984-04-01 **01**:00:00' in DBeaver and Aqua Data Studio and '1984-04-01 **00**:00:00' in Hue.
Why?

Comment: THis may be a local system related issue. what is the timezone of the machine you are using DBeaver from? can you use TO_UTC_TIMESTAMP() and see if this inconsistency exists ?

Comment: TO_UTC_TIMESTAMP('01041984', 'ddMMyyyy') returns NULL

Comment: sorry, i mean to say `UNIX_TIMESTAMP('01041984', 'ddMMyyyy'),` ? to UTC will convert a timestamp to UTC.